# Failed to start reference finalizer thread

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

I am using admin sdk, spring mvc, cloud sql, servlet. I have done the openid autentication.
But while processing the authentication , I getting below exception. Can anyone tell me what i need to do..?

```
    Failed to start reference finalizer thread. Reference cleanup will only occur 
    when  new references are created.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.inject.internal.FinalizableReferenceQueue.<init>(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:124)
at com.google.inject.internal.MapMaker$QueueHolder.<clinit>(MapMaker.java:787)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)

    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access 
     denied  (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup) 
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532) 
       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:383)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:408)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you look at it, this is or isn't a bug ;)
Appengine is a pretty restrictive environment and Guice is using a repackaged version of old Guava that tries to perform some cleanup tasks. However this isn't possible in that environment, hence error message. This does eat up some CPU, but your app should run fine anyway.

An offered solution to hide the messages is to change the logging level for those messages, by running: `Logger.getLogger("com.google.inject.internal.util").setLevel(Level.WARNING);` on app startup.

Guice teams promises the problem will disappear in the upcoming version. 4.0 is currently in beta, so the problem should finally be gone soon. You can check out the beta yourself too.

More info on the problem is here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=488